# PHP: How can i create links from a variable?

Tags: php, variables

The variable looks like this:

```
$keywords = 'key1, key2, key3, key4';
```

How can i create links like:

```
<a href="../tag/key1">key1</a>, <a href="../tag/key2">key2</a>, <a href="../tag/key3">key3</a>, <a href="../tag/key4">key4</a>
```

using php?

---

// Edited

What if $is defined with

```
$keywords = 'key1, keyword two, key3, key four';
```

or even other order?

```
<a href="../tag/key1">key1</a>, <a href="../tag/keyword+two">keyword two</a>, <a href="../tag/key3">key3</a>, <a href="../tag/key+four">key four</a>
```

i mean, if one of the 'keyword' it is formed from two words add a '+' sign between them at the link

How can this been done?

Comment: @Balanivash -- looks like a string to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
foreach(explode(', ',$keywords) as $value){
    echo "<a href='../tag/$value'>$value</a>";
}
```

---

To do with commas:

```
$keyArray = explode(', ',$keywords);
$keyLength = count($keyArray);
foreach($keyArray as $key=>$value){
    echo "<a href='../tag/$value'>$value</a>";
    if($key < ($keyLength - 1)){
          echo ", ";
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE TO OP**:

```
$keyArray = explode(', ',$keywords);
$keyLength = count($keyArray);
foreach($keyArray as $key=>$value){
    echo "<a href='../tag/";
    $vArr = explode(' ', $value);
    $vLength = count($vArr);
    foreach($vArr as $kv=>$v){
         echo $v;
         if($kv < ($vLength - 1))  echo "+";
    }
    echo "'>$value</a>";
    if($key < ($keyLength - 1)){
          echo ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you beat me by a second!  Apart from saving a line are their any benefits to doing your explode inside the foreach?

Comment: @TimCooper i added the commas although im not sure why :-P

Comment: @Toby ur way might be better (in my way it has to get the index of the explode every time)

Comment: @Neal: That adds an unnecessary comma to the end of the list.

Comment: I am going to run some tests.

Comment: @Tim: am not sure if the commas are a part of the question, think they are just separators between examples of the types of links m3tsys wants to make.

Comment: @Balanivash it seems that @TimCooper is very picky (i just hope not my nose!)

Comment: @m3tsys -- remember to select an accepted answer, i see ur only at `67%` and some people might be deterred by that in the future

Comment: @m3tsys -- no problem ^_^ anytime :-D

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you want to do is explode that string.

```
$links = explode(',', $keywords);
```

Then you want to loop it...

```
for($counter = 0; $counter < sizeof($links); $counter++) {
    if($counter > 0) {
        echo ", ";
    }
    echo "<a href='../tag/".str_replace(' ', '+', trim($link[$counter]))."'>{$link[$counter]}</a>";
}
```

Comment: @Toby, now it definitely does

Comment: Nope, so the first time around the loop no comma, then every other time until the end of the loop the `<a>` will be prefaced with a comma.

Comment: thank you, but it has a problem:     `<a href='../tag/funny'>funny</a>, <a href='../tag/+video+funny'> video funny</a>`

Comment: it has a space in in the from the link text and a + in the front of the tag name...

Comment: I have now trimmed the text first.  Please update your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

The following is updated to your new requirements:

```
function keyword_url($arr)
{
    return sprintf('%s<a href="../tag/%s">%s</a>', $arr[1], urlencode($arr[2]), $arr[2]);
}

$keywords = 'key1, key2 piece, key3, key4';
echo preg_replace_callback('/((?:^)|(?:, *))([\w ]+)/', 'keyword_url', $keywords);
```

Comment: Does this solve the leading space issue if the keyword is ' funny pictures'?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php  $keyword = explode(',',$keywords); ?> 
 <a href="../tag/<?php echo $keyword[0]; ?>">key1</a>
 <a href="../tag/<?php echo $keyword[2]; ?>">key3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First use explode() to split your keyword string into an array

From there there are a number of ways to turn an array into a series or array of strings. You could even use implode to bring an array of link strings back into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$keywords = 'key1, key2, key3, key4';

$vars = explode(',',$keywords);
foreach($vars as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<a href="'.$value.'" title="' . $value . '">'.$value.'</a><br/>';
}
?>
```